# How do I install Clang 4.0 or above on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tesseract-ocr, clang

I need to install Clang 3.4 and above on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, as a prerequisite to [this Package](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract#installing-tesseract) that I need to use.

Not sure should if I go for the latest Clang version, and if yes, how can I do it for the Ubuntu I am using? Or, would Clang 4.0 suffice?

Then, how would I install Clang 4.0 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install clang`? You can install Tesseract by `apt-get` as well, but by Ubuntu 16.04 you will have an earlier version.

Comment: @Marco Thank you. I have tried that, in addition to so many other approaches mentioned on the web. I am getting this error
`Fetched 45.9 MB in 37s (1,228 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package libobjc4:amd64.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'gnome-user-guide': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
`